# Not full-wave signal transmission?

Tags: frequency, radio, transmission, em

Is it possible to transmit half-wave signals repetitively, like repetitive *"north"* magnetic fields like going from 0-1 Gauss *"north"* and repeat however many times per second without going *0-north-0-south* like a full-wave signal?

Comment: If you transmit a bunch of half-sin-waves, the antennas will filter out most of the faster energy, and your energy peak will become at TWICE the carrier.

Comment: Diodes are used as distorted harmonic generators or filtered frequency doublers for microwave but other than that , not much use as the DC energy is lost in antenna

Comment: What's your goal here?  There's no *meaningful* "absolute voltage" in transmitting as only the derivatives can propagate, so your idea that this is unipolar is for all practical purposes mistaken once you get beyond the antenna.  However such a distorted waveform will be spectrally ugly, with likely *illegal* overtone content.

Comment: the idea is to have satellites transmit a magnetosphere over Mars lol

Comment: ...as to make it habitable within a few years according to NASA - it just needs a magnetosphere. this is all hypothetical unless I get super rich, then I will start a country, the people would vote for the laws and drones would do all of the work. new world order??

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations): There are nabla operators in them - these will only pick up *changes* in the value over time.

That means the receiver will ignore any DC offset regardless whether it is magnetic or electric (unless it is very very close to the sender).

Also note that rectifying a (HF?) signal will change it in the frequency domain quite a bit - which *does* affect the receiver.

Comment: not intending to receive a signal, only intending to transmit halfwave signals; would half instead of full wave signals be able to transmit? the idea is for an artificial Martian magnetosphere.